# Use htmlspecialchars but allow <a href="URL">...</a>

Tags: php

Use htmlspecialchars but allow `<a href="URL">...</a>`.
Extra spaces should also be valid, like `< a href =`.

---

```
$pureHTML = htmlspecialchars($dirtyHTML,ENT_QUOTES);
```

Now maybe I need a `preg_replace` on `$pureHTML`, but what should be the `preg_replace`? Or do you recommend using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)?

I want to allow anchor tag pair only for href attribute. Onclick, target attributes are not allowed.

Comment: a little more information ... or words would be useful

Comment: You need to use regular expression for that

Comment: You have not framed your question properly.

Comment: he wants to htmlspecialchars a string but keeping anchors from being escaped.

Comment: why don't you just write your own function, what you want to allow and what you want to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can get this in a single replace as you would have to match and replace the "<a" and ">" surrounding the href, while leaving it intact.  the closing "<a>" is an easy replace thought.  There could be a way to do this all in a single preg_replace, but I'm not proficient enough in regex to do so.. anyway I would do

```
$pureHTML = htmlspecialchars($dirtyHTML, ENT_NOQUOTES);
preg_match_all('/(&lt;\s*a)\s*(\w+="[\w:\/@#%_\-&\.]+")\s*(&gt;)/i', $pureHTML, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $pureHTML = str_replace($match[0], "<a " . $match[2] . ">", $pureHTML);
}
$pureHTML = preg_replace('/(&lt;\/\s*a\s*&gt;)/i', '</a>', $pureHTML);
```

Basically, it matches the escaped form of `(<a)(href="url")(>)`, allowing for spaces between each part (also space between "<" and "a"). It then replaces the original match with literal `<a(href="url")>`

And then just does a direct string replace of the escaped form of  (allowing for spaces)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [strip-tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
$pureHTML =  strip_tags($html, '<a>');
```